# Каким образом можно записать в таблицу БД ms sql, таблицу созданную вручную в DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sql-server, datagridview

Пытаюсь вставить данные из таблицы `DataGridView` в таблицу MSSQL. Ошибок никаких нет, но и в таблице данные не появляются...

Вот мой странный код:

```
using (DBConnection.connection = new SqlConnection(DBConnection.connectionString))
{
    DBConnection.connection.Open();
    DBConnection.adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(DBConnection.spGetAllItinerary, DBConnection.connection);
    DBConnection.commandBilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(DBConnection.adapter);
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvItinerary.Rows)
    {
        DBConnection.adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(DBConnection.spInsertItinerary, DBConnection.connection);
        DBConnection.adapter.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DBConnection.adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@country",  row.Cells["CountryColumnItinerary"].Value)); ;
        DBConnection.adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@startPoint", row.Cells["StarPointColumn"].Value));
        DBConnection.adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@final", row.Cells["FinalPointColumn"].Value));
        DBConnection.adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@mileage", row.Cells["MileageColumn"].Value));
        DBConnection.adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cargo", row.Cells["CargoColumn"].Value));
        DBConnection.adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cmr", row.Cells["CMRColumn"].Value));
        DBConnection.adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@labelTransit", row.Cells["TransitColumn"].Value));
        DBConnection.adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@labelEAEU", row.Cells["EAEUColumn"].Value));
        DBConnection.adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@waybillNumber", tbNumberWaybill.Text));
    }
}
```

Может кто-то знает как это делается?

Comment: я не могу без усилий ответить на Ваш вопрос полностью, но, мне кажется, я вижу в коде некую странность: вы (на многих строчках подряд) задаёте параметры той команды, которая должна сделать insert, но потом... не говорите "сделать инсерт". То есть, установили параметры - и вышли из процедуры. Думаю, нужно что то вроде table.Rows.Add(newRow); или adapter.Update(table);, подробнее - здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/modifying-data-with-a-dbdataadapter

Answer (score 0):

Тут формируется команда, но не выполняется.
В конце необходимо добавить:

```
adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Могу ошибаться с точной формулировкой, но проблема пустой таблицы в отсутствии запуска команды INSERT